# if no value in database i recieve an error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

for some reason this works just fine on wamp but if put it on shared host i get the following error message, to some extent i guess its because there is no records in db so negative value is being passed and this is happening only if database is empty.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1210 Incorrect arguments to mysqld_stmt_execute
```

i tried var_dump and this is the output

```
var_dump($offset);
var_dump($per_page);
var_dump($uid);

float(-10) 
int(10) 
int(4)
```

here is my coding

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 

$query = "SELECT * FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

thanks in advance, appreciate your time

Comment: The only solution is to amend the code to cope with no rows on the table. You know your system, we dont, only you can make the decision on what to do with no data in this situation

Comment: it would fail on WAMP as well if there were no rows in the table so thats irrelevant

Comment: you are right @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace php code with these

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $total = $stmt->fetchColumn();    

$pages = ceil($total / $per_page);

$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
'options' => array(
'default'   => 1,
'min_range' => 1,
),
)));

$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 
if($offset < 0){
$offset = 10;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM applied WHERE memberID = :memberID ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT :per_page OFFSET :offset";

         $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
         $stmt->bindParam(':per_page', $per_page, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->bindParam(':memberID', $uid, PDO::PARAM_INT);
         $stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Why should the OP "use this code"? A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer.

Comment: thanks mate it works but do you know how exactly am i getting  offset value as -10 the database is completely empty then why is it -10 other than -0?

Comment: `$offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; ` when `$page = 0` this evaluates to `$offset = (-1) * 10` i.e. `-10`

Comment: This is all well and good. But now you need to check that the code following this can also cope with getting NO rows in `$result` This has just moved the issue onto the next block of code

Comment: thanks appreciate it @RiggsFolly but is $offset = ($page - 1)  * $per_page; 
if($offset < 0){
$offset = 10;
} the only solution for this? i actually had tried something similar and was expecting maybe someone here would come up with a better solution

Comment: To be honset that just makes the query syntax for the following query valid i.e. you are no longer passing `-10` to `OFFSET :offset`. The query should of course return no rows as we already know there are none to return

Comment: If the code that processes `$result` can cope **elegantly** with an empty array then you are golden

Comment: had been having a real hard time with this as pdo is new to me. could you give a better option your way? would appreciate it mate